# Nginx doesn't redirect to index.php page of phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, centos7

I just installed nginx, php-fpm and phpmyadmin.
This is my www folder.

```
[root@vmi67073 etc]# ll /usr/share/nginx/html/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3650 Feb 13 18:45 404.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3693 Feb 13 18:45 50x.html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   40 Mar 17 06:14 myapp.eu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3700 Feb 13 18:45 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Mar 17 06:52 mysql -> /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
```

My nginx conf file location for phpmyadmin under myapp.conf file looks like this

```
location /mysql {
        alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

Problem:
If i try to access `myapp.eu/mysql` i get following error in nginx log

```
2016/03/17 09:21:01 [error] 2119#0: *28 directory index of "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/" is forbidden, client: 84.52.168.135, server: euro-swap.eu, request: "GET /mysql/ HTTP/1.1", host: "euro-swap.eu"
```

But if i try to access `myapp.eu/mysql/index.php` phpmyadmin is shown. So i'm guessing that nginx should somehow redirect to index.php page.

What is causing this problem? How to fix it? If you need any additional information's, please let me know and i will provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to open `myapp.eu/mysql`, its being catched by outer `location` directive. But no index defined for outer one. So solution is to move index directive there from inner `location`:

```
location /mysql {
        alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the second location. `location ~ \.php$` matches paths which end with `.php`, and your one is not: `/mysql`. Try to remove it.

```
location /mysql {
    alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution for running phpmyadmin on a subdomain.

Plus next time I have this issue I know I'll be able to copy/paste my own solution :)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name secret-sql-subdomain.site.com;
    root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
    location / {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```